# Update programmatic Layout from a SurfaceView inside the Layout

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview

So, I have searched for an answer. Most results show how to update from outside the Layout. Here is my simplified code.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        surface.addView(new UnitActivity(this));}}
```

UnitActivity:

```
public class UnitActivity extends SurfaceView
{
    private MainThread thread;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    public UnitActivity(Context context){
        super(context);touch = new MyTouchListener();
        this.setOnTouchListener(touch);

        thread = new MainThread(this);
        holder=getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){    
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder p1)
            {
                thread.setRunning(true);
                thread.start();         
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder p1)
            {
                boolean retry = true;
                while (retry)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        thread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                    }
                }
            }       
        });
    setFocusable(true)
    }
    @Override 
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        //draw to canvas here
        *******Here is where I want to, in some way 
        make a call to add a ScrollView or 
        TextView to the original Layout******
    }
}
```

Basically, my `SurfaceView` is updating running a `Thread`. I want a certain condition to trigger a `TextView` or `ScrollView` to become visible on screen. I thought maybe I could just get the Layout to run a thread and update itself, but killed my app doing so... I appreciate any help or comments.

Comment: Killed your app... how?  What did it die from?

Comment: I meant the cutting up my code and re arranging it, just made it not run. When I did make it stop getting untangled errors, it wouldn't display the SurfaceView. But I want to get the above idea running or a better way of performing the task.

Comment: Ok,  so to clarify, I want to update my Layout from a programmatic View contained in said Layout. Is it possible, if so how? If not, how should I go about making my desired outcome happen?